# Linking to Netsuite for Android/iOS in Suitescript

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, netsuite, suitescript

Does anyone know if there is a hyperlink prefix that can used to direct a link to the Netsuite App in either Android of iOS.

For example, I have a record requiring approval, so my script sends an email to the approver with a link to the record within Netsuite. If they recipient has the Netsuite App for Android/iOS installed, the record would be opened with the App instead of opening the record in the device's web browser.

Given the Android netsuite app has been dramatically improved, it's now a good tool to use.